# Is an ellipse uniquely defined by it's center, a point on it and it's eccentricity?

Tags: geometry

Is an ellipse uniquely defined by it's center, a point on it and it's eccentricity? If it is, how would one go about constructing an ellipse given those parameters?

Origin of the question: I'm trying to generalize a configuration made up of a central circle and three other circles, each having it's center on the central circle and passing through the central circle's center.

Comment: No. Given one ellipse with the specified center and eccentricity, you can freely rotate and scale it to get a two-parameter family of ellipses with the same center and eccentricity. For each rotation, you can find a scaling that makes the ellipse pass through the specified point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If $O$ is the center and $P$ is the given point on the ellipse, you can always draw at least two ellipses:  one with $OP$ as a semimajor axis and one with $OP$ as a semiminor axis.

These actually represent, respectively, the smallest and largest ellipses of a family.  See Yves's answer.

Answer (score 2):

An ellipse, like any conic, has five degrees of freedom, such as the coordinates of the center and the length and direction of the axes.

The center and eccentricity resolve three parameters and a point "on it" only one, because it can be anywhere along the curve. Hence a single indeterminacy remains.